# Error fetching value of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagrid on user control, which "modifier" is made public. I have the following code:

```
for (int f = 0; f < gridOperations.Rows.Count; f++)
{
     for (int z = 0; f < gridOperations.Rows[f].Cells.Count; z++)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(gridOperations.Rows[f].Cells[z].Value.ToString());
     }
}
```

The problem is that if Z becomes higher than 0 it gives me

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

I don't understand why is this happening, if I do:

```
MessageBox.Show(gridOperations.Rows[0].Cells.Count.ToString());
```

It shows 9 items, so there are cells, I just don't understand why it doesn't let me access them. Thanks!

Comment: Have you test my answer? any exceptions?

Comment: @Damith I tested and I'm still getting the same exception, weird.. any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: how you bind datagridview? which column you want to get value?

Comment: @Damith I bind List<customClass> to dataSource. Second column

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Value !=null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same exception

Comment: @Kristian added null check, please check

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like this ..

```
for (int f = 0; f < gridOperations.Rows.Count-1; f++)
{
     for (int z = 0; f < gridOperations.ColumnCount -1; z++)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(gridOperations.Rows(f).Cells(z).Value.ToString());
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It says gridOperations doesnt contain definition of 'Cells' Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting exception. The datagrid uses DataSource, could that be a problem?

Comment: @Kristian : Maybe cozed by '[]' .. try again

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
for (int f = 0; f < gridOperations.Rows.Count; f++)
{
     for (int z = 0; z < gridOperations.Rows[f].Cells.Count; z++)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(gridOperations.Rows[f].Cells[z].Value.ToString());
     }
}
```

I think the real problem is here, you bounded your inside `for` loop with `f < gridOperations.Rows[f].Cells.Count` whihc I think should be `z < gridOperations.Rows[f].Cells.Count` because your bound for that loop should be the cell count of the current row, not the number of the current row.

As an alternative, since [`DataGridViewRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.aspx) and [`DataGridViewCellCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellcollection.aspx) implements [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface, you can use `foreach` loop like;

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in gridOperations.Rows)
{                            
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cells in rows.Cells)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(cells.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The same nullReferenceException occurs and the second example doesn't compile (Object doesn't contain 'Cells')

Comment: @Kristian Updated second example. You can check it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the null exception. It only works when cellID is 0, when it's 1, I get the exception.